# .zshrc is not loaded in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am experimenting whether I can check the version of `bundle` in localhost using `ansible-playbook local.yml` as shown in `local.yml` below.

- local.yml

  ```
  ---

  - hosts: local
    remote_user: someuser
    tasks:
        - name: Check bundle version
          shell: "{{ansible_user_shell}} -l -c 'bundle --version'"
          args:
               chdir: "/path/to/rails/dir"
  ```

Inventory file is as follows:

- hosts

  ```
  [local]
      127.0.0.1
  [local:vars]
      ansible_ssh_user=someuser
  ```

However I got the error saying,

> stderr: zsh:1: command not found: bundle`

I have no idea why I am getting this error because I confirmed bundle is installed on localhost. Also I found that shell module does not use login shell so environmental variables in .zshrc is not loaded so I ran zsh with `-l`(use login shell) option. But it's not working. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This might be related how Ansible does sudo - it might not set `$HOME` making .zshrc  coming from the wrong user. Or something along the lines - guessing here.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thank you for you answer. I actually figured out by myself .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem by myself. The problem was the configuration of zsh. I thought .zshrc is executed on every login. This is inaccurate because .zshrc is only loaded on login and **interactive** shell. In the above case, the command is **NOT** run on interactive shell so .zshrc was not loaded.
To load .zshrc every time I use login shell, I created `.zprofile` which is loaded on login shell as follows:

```
# include .zshrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.zshrc" ]; then
  . "$HOME/.zshrc"
fi
```

Another solution might be to add -i(interactive shell) option :)

Comment: Came here for same kind of problem with rbenv command, spliited zshrc into zshrc and zprofile for the same winning result

Comment: Tried this but didn't work for me. I looked at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71258/116606

It says `.zprofile` is loaded if it's a login shell, so I guess ansible just doesn't run its commands via a login shell (anymore?).

Instead I put this in `~/.zshenv` and it works then.

+1 for pointing me in the right direction though :)

Comment: **NOTE:** Adding this to `.zprofile` and/or `.zshenv` will make `.zshrc` two/three times when creating a new interactive shell!

Comment: I just added the code snippet to `.zshenv` and it works, thanks!